# Swap two elements in ArrayList inside custom adapter to show in Listview

Tags: android

I have a Listview and a custom adapter, I am trying to change swap two arraylist items inside the apdapter in onclick of button as listview item.
My code is

```
viewHolder.btnUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Integer pos = (Integer) v.getTag();

            if (!pojos.get(pos).equals(pojos.get(0))) {

                Collections.swap(pojos, pos, pos - 1);

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
```

But I can not see the changes in listview, though arraylist has modified, but UI changes has not reflected.

Comment: There'll be two things I'd check. 1.Is `pojos` the arraylist you're using as the data source for the adapter. 2. I think you might need to call notifyDataSetChaged() to run on UI Thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because your adapter has already finished its work. The adapter will turn the data into views and pass those views to the list view. Notice that changing the order in the original collection wont change the views inside the list view. What you could do is remove the views and add them at the correct positions. Get access to the list view by doing viewHolder.getParent()

Comment: It looks good, so how can i remove views and add them again inside adapter?

Comment: call getParent() on the item to get a reference to the list view and then do removeViewAt(position)

Comment: adding and removing view creating mess, so i just made a method inside activity to set adapter again and that method is called from adapter.It works perfectly but I know it doesn't sound a very good practice.

Comment: add and remove at positions

Comment: I really don't think he should be trying to manually remove and swap the views themselves.  He should be able to manipulate the dataset and call notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: yeah he should, i didnt pay attention to that custom adapter

Comment: He stated he has an adapter in the question.  Plus he has a ListView so he has to have one.

Comment: my bad. I was incorrect. Yeah he should go with notify data set changed

Answer (score 0):

If pojos is a local final variable, make sure the one the adaptor uses still points to the same collection otherwise the anonymous class will swap 2 elements in an collection that's not being used.

Comment: pojos is the dataset which I have passed to adapter so its not local and final. This is done same as checkbox in each list item, where checkbox reflects the changes but this does not work. I have tried with runOnUIThread also but did not work

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to pass the `arrayList` to the adapter again and setting adapter to the list view, all this before the `notifyDataSetChanged();` method.